# Responsive jQuery or JavaScript framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

Is there any jQuery or JavaScript responsive design framework?  Or certain standards to follow when certain variable values need to change or even when changing functions based on screen size?

Currently I am using:

```
if (jQuery(window).width() <= 767 ){
}

jQuery(window).resize(function(){
 if (jQuery(window).width() <= 767 ){
 }
});
```

Is this okay? Or is there a better, more stable method?

Comment: Have you heard of [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)? Making a site responsive will usually be done without javascript..

Comment: Hey, Yes I have but i am specifically looking for javascript or jquery, for animation purposes that need to run on ie8 so... CSS is not a viable option..

Comment: This is something that I don't really understand, why making a site responsive on IE8? Do you run IE8 on any mobile device?

Comment: CSS is the *correct* option - it will work in far more cases than pure JS will. If older IE browsers are your target, use https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

Comment: Or better just use [twitter bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and its [responsive templates](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples)

Comment: `Respond.Js` will give you some `media-querying` capabilities in IE8 too.

Comment: Really? Look i am not arguing that css isn't better of course it is better, but i need an animation that has different values for its variables on a iphone and on desktop and it needs to work on ie8 so i cant use css3 animation

Comment: Yes!, thank you exactly like jRespond...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some options like

- jRespond (Pure javascript)  https://github.com/ten1seven/jRespond
- Responsejs (jQuery plugin)  http://responsejs.com/
- Or some other tools  http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/rwd-tools/

Comment: Thank you, looks good, one more question.. if i am already loading jquery on my site for other modules, is it better to use the pure javascript option still? or since i am already loading jquery i may aswell stick with it?

Comment: Use what you think it suits best for you and where you feel at your best. I love jQuery because it is so easy and I don't have to think about all those browsers and EMCA script versions. I have read your comment that you want to animate, so probably jQuery would be easier.